# Apparent violation of laws of reflection for an inertial observer

Tags: visible-light, reflection, speed-of-light

I am actually having an introductory course in Special Relativity in which I was looking at the Michelson Morley experiment. And I have this silly confusion.

The setup for the Michelson Morley experiment looks something like this in every textbook (assuming the observer is in the comoving frame)

[image]

When this same setup is being observed by the observer in the hypothetical frame of "ether" (which this experiment was designed to detect) , then the vertical beam of the light is no more vertical but along the hypotenuse(the dashed red line) and this should be true so that the two observers agree on the results of the experiment.

[image]

But I really don't understand why the light should not go vertically as **the shown path of the light beam seems to violate the laws of reflection as the angle of incidence is no more equal to the angle of reflection**.

**So how can then the two inertial frames be equivalent ?**

**PS** :- Nobody in the class bothered about this, not even the instructor of the course.